# Transfer gridview data to other form and other labels

Tags: asp.net

I am a newbie in using asp.net, I have a problem on how to transfer these data below on other form!

The scenario is like this after the user clicks the Enter Button it shows a message box that the sales is updated and after that it will transfer to other form that shows in figure 2. Can you give me idea. thanks in advance :D. here's my code.

**Date and Time**

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


        'DATE AND TIME
        lbl_date.Text = FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.LongDate)
        lbl_time.Text = FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.LongTime)
end Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can send any object via session.
In the first form set the session to your datatable object and get it in the second form

```
  Session("dataTable") = datatable
```

and in the second form get the object stored in the session

```
  Dim data As DataTable = DirectCast(Session("dataTable"), DataTable)
```

Comment: which part of my code should I place the  Session("dataTable") = datatable?

Comment: When you want to Redirect to the second page

Comment: the second page which i need to redirect shows that the DataTable is not defined??? an idea I'm transferring it OFFICIALRECEIPT.ASPX

Comment: don't forget to import System.Data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6095/discussion-between-sleiman-jneidi-and-carisle)